# wx can't be imported in python Idle window

Tags: python, wxpython

Although I have installed the module wx, when I try to import wx in python 2.7.9 idle window it is giving me the following error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 6, in <module>
    new_instancemethod = new.instancemethod
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'instancemethod'`

Comment: Do you happen to have any python modules named `new` that is a file named `new.py`?

Comment: **yes**  I happen to **have a new.py** is it due to that @SelçukCihan